# Solving a difference equation with several parameters

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let $r>4$ be a positive integer. Let us consider this difference equation:
$$u_{q+1}=(r^{2q+1}+(c/a))u_{q}-(c/a)r^{2q-1}u_{q-1} +2c+d-(bc/a)$$

where $a,b,c,d$ are integers.

I want to find a closed form, but I am not able to find the good idea. **Or at least how we can prove that a solution exists**.

Comment: what's the coefficient of $u_q$?

Comment: @Alex: It is $(r^{2q+1}+(c/a))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same technique as before. Expand using a symbolic algebra system on the computer. Find a pattern. Prove by induction.

$$
\begin{array} (
&\displaystyle u_n =  u_1 r^{f(n)} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left[ \alpha^k (u_1 - u_0 r) + \tfrac{\alpha^k-1}{\alpha-1}\gamma \right] r^{f(n)-g(k)} \\
& \\
&f(n) = n^2-1 \\
&g(k) = k\,(k+2) \\
& \\
& \alpha = c/a \\
& \gamma = 2c + d -bc/a \\
\end{array}
$$

which is fairly nice if $u_0=u_1=0$.