# About solving a second order difference equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let $r>4$ be a positive integer. I want to solve this difference equation:

$$u_{n+1}-r²(1+r²ⁿ⁺¹)u_{n}+r²r²ⁿ⁺¹u_{n-1}-2r²r²ⁿ⁺¹=0$$ but I have no a good idea to start.

Comment: Isn't this a minor variation on your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1138033 ?

Comment: @Did: Yes, but the method does not works well.

Comment: @Did: No, the two questions are different.

Comment: "Yes, but the method does not works well." ?? Which method? What are you talking about? Why didn't you mention the other question?

Comment: @Did: You can see the usual method of summation to reduce it to a first order equation does not works for this case.

Comment: Where can I see "the usual method" since you do not present it, neither here nor there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expanded your recurrence

$$ u_n = \left(r^2 + r^{2n+1}\right) u_{n-1} - \left( r^{2n+1} \right) u_{n-2} + 2r^{2n+1} $$

using Sympy and found a general solution in terms of $u_0$ and $u_1$.

$$ 
u_n = u_1\, r^{f(n)} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \left[ \left( 2k+2-u_0 \right) r^3 + u_1 \right] r^{f(n)-g(k)} \\ \; \\
\begin{array} (
&f(n) = n^2 + 2n - 3 \\
&g(k) = k^2 + 4k + 3\\
\end{array}
$$

which can be proved by induction. However, unless you can simplify this further, it's not much more computationally useful than the recurrence. As an example, here is the expanded form of $u_{10}$ when $u_0=u_1=0$.

$$ u_{10} = 2r^{117} + 4r^{112} + 6r^{105} + 8r^{96} + 10r^{85} + 12r^{72} + 14r^{57} + 16r^{40} + 18r^{21} $$